# Bootstrap column system, line break even with col-md-4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently trying to use Bootstrap to get two columns: One width 1/3 size and one with 2/3 size.

What I have is a container, and in it a row:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      asfas asijnafninasifn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100-img" src="image.png" alt="" usemap="#image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" width="6460" height="3455" border="0" class="map" />
      <map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" name="image-maps-2017-08-25-161100"></map>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the expected result for me (in my understanding) would be 1/3 of the page with the text and linebreaks and 2/3 (on the right side) would be the image with the image-map on it.

But: the result is both underneath, so in one line there is this thex text (within `col-md-4`) and on the next line there is the image (within `col-md-8)`. Where is the problem?

Info: My viewport is big enough and even changing is to `xs` doesn't change the result.

Comment: On the right side you use an image with HUGE dimensions: `width="6460" `. How is that supposed to fit?

Comment: @connexo well, on the normal page it fits, too. the container has a max-width of 1160px, but still the image fits in their. So why shouldn't it fit in the column, too?

Comment: Because Bootstrap columns do not have a max-width. They are done in Bootstrap 3 using floats. Floats that don't fit next to another wrap underneath. Giving the `<img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />` might fix it.

Comment: @connexo and what my alternative then? So how can I put the image on the right side and the text (or sth. else) on the left side with a 1/3 2/3 ratio?

Comment: See I edited my last comment.

Comment: @connexo doesn't change anything.. actually a non bootstrap version would be okay for me too, but I need to get it working somehow

Answer (score 0):

As written in your comments, this DOES work:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      asfas asijnafninasifn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Su%C3%ADno_alta.jpg" alt="" usemap="#image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" width="6460" height="3455" border="0" class="map" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto !important" />
      <map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" name="image-maps-2017-08-25-161100"></map>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no it doesn't... for me its still the same problem, I wrote that it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Click "Expand Snippet", then "Run Code snippet". It DOES work.

Comment: yes, I saw that it is working here, but it doesn't change the behaviour on my page, where it is just not working... so there has to be another problem then

Comment: but what else could be the problem? Even if in developer tools, I untick every other css property then the `max-width` and the `height`, its still two rows and not in one..

Comment: See I analysed what is causing the problem you described given the code you presented. I presented the solution to that. So if you have others problems on top of the one I solved for you, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

For small screen use `col-sm-4` and `col-xs-4` because `col-md-4` taking 992px and up screen. One important thing for image, give `img-reponsive` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      asfas asijnafninasifn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn<br/>afasfn
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
      <img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff&text=sample+image" alt="" usemap="#image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" border="0" class="map img-responsive" />
      <map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100" name="image-maps-2017-08-25-161100"></map>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```